# Error: Cannot create instance of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps.MapControl' on Windows 10 Desktop

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile

I receive this error when trying to deploy my app to my desktop, but it works fine when deploying to Windows 10 phones. Any ideas on how to fix this?

The namespace:

```
xmlns:Maps="using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps"
```

XAML usage:

```
<Grid>
    <Maps:MapControl />
</Grid>
```

I don't have any other logic just trying to display the map for now.

EDIT:
Turns out the [MapControl sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/MapControl) from the Windows Universal Samples Github works on desktops (and phones) other than the desktops at my work.

Thanks to Andrew Pilley for pointing me to the Github.

Still looking for a reason this would not work on some Windows 10 desktops? The desktops are running and the project is targeting build 10240.

Comment: Does the [MapControl sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/MapControl) from the Windows Universal Samples Github work? Also, you didn't include any kind of error you received.

Comment: Have you provided your map with the `CredentialsProvider` property?

Comment: When trying to run the github example on desktop, I'm receiving the same error (as mentioned in the title): 'WinRT information: Cannot create instance of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps.MapControl' [Line: 89 Position: 38]' . If I create an app package and install the app does not crash but no map ever appears. The does work on Windows 10 phone just like my own example. No I did not provide the CredentialsProvider property. It should just display a warning though like it does on mobile, right?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Bing Maps SDK ?

VS Gallery Ref : https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/224eb93a-ebc4-46ba-9be7-90ee777ad9e1